# My raspberry pi shows supported = 0 detected = 0 when I connect my camera

Tags: camera, lcd

My camera was running alright on my pc before, but after connecting my lcd touchscreen with Raspberry Pi 3B+ and when I try running the command vcgencmd get_camera I get supported = 0 and detected = 0. I have enabled legacy camera through sudo raspi-config. Even start_x and gpu_mem=128 are not commented in config.txt. I have also updated and upgraded my Pi and I plug in the camera before booting it. I am using Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I am using a Raspberry Pi belt connection camera.
Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Comment: how did you connect the camera to your PC? ... is it a USB camera?

Comment: Hi, please try to use the same account while editing the question you have posted, otherwise it looks as if someone else is trying to hijack it.